# Does using a syncing software like resilio sync reduce the life of your hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, sync, resilio-sync

I'm using resilio sync to sync some large folders (Some go upto 200GB) between two local machines. Is this a good idea? Can constant indexing and syncing reduce the lifetime of my hard drives?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things, not least of which is whether or not you are using an ssd, or traditional platter set disk. Second largest factor i would say is whether encryption is involved and how. Thirdly, folders might be large, but files also? how many need updating. Whats is the *real* update bandwidth required?

Comment: @Nalaurien Actually all drives are HDDs. Not SSDs and there's no encryption involved. The folders have many types of files including large videos and small text files. They does not update very frequently but the syncing program does scan them all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure it would make any reasonable difference. For regular hdds anyway. Most sync software only index new additions, and only sync new files. So long as you have timestamps enabled in config and don't use encrypted containers that have to be updated in whole each time a change is made, I don't think you would see any noticeable wear on a hard drive that you wouldn't replace 3-5 years from now anyway. It would be the same if you were copying the files from USB each time.